# Changing background of spinner items based on sqlite data

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, custom-adapter

I am changing the background color of the items in my spinner based on the data provided by my SQLite query. I've used `getDropDownView` method to check the data and change the background color.

Now let's suppose I have 2 records on my SQLite table with ids 1 and 2. The issue that I'm facing is that only the last record (in this case record with id: 2) gets the background color. This is what I'm doing:

```
    ArrayAdapter<Category> categoryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Category>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, categoryList){
                @Override
                public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                    View row = null;
                    Category category = (Category) getItem(position);
                    Cursor crsCheckCatAva = database.rawQuery("SELECT distinct category_id FROM "+ ItemsTable.TABLE_OUTLET_DATA +" WHERE "+ ItemsTable.COLUMN_OUTLET_DATA_OUTLET_ID +"='"+ Info.getInstance().getOutletID() +"'", null);
                    if(crsCheckCatAva.getCount() > 0){
                        while (crsCheckCatAva.moveToNext()){
                            if(crsCheckCatAva.getInt(crsCheckCatAva.getColumnIndex("category_id")) == category.getCategory_id()){
                                row = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                                row.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                            }else {
                                row = super.getDropDownView(position, null, parent);
                                row.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                            }
                        }
                    }else {
                        row = super.getDropDownView(position, null, parent);
                    }
                    crsCheckCatAva.close();

                    return row;
                }
            };
 categorySelectionSpinner.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
```

This is the output:

```
01-15 19:19:16.361 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 0
01-15 19:19:16.362 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 0
01-15 19:19:16.363 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 4
01-15 19:19:16.363 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 4
01-15 19:19:16.364 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 6
01-15 19:19:16.365 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 6
01-15 19:19:16.366 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 7
01-15 19:19:16.366 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 7
01-15 19:19:16.368 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 8
01-15 19:19:16.368 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 8
01-15 19:19:16.370 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 26
01-15 19:19:16.371 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 26
01-15 19:19:16.372 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 27
01-15 19:19:16.372 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 27
01-15 19:19:16.373 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 28
01-15 19:19:16.374 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 28
01-15 19:19:16.375 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 29
01-15 19:19:16.375 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 29
01-15 19:19:16.379 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 30
01-15 19:19:16.381 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 30
01-15 19:19:16.382 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 31
01-15 19:19:16.382 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 31
01-15 19:19:16.386 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 0
01-15 19:19:16.387 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 0
01-15 19:19:16.388 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 4
01-15 19:19:16.388 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 4
01-15 19:19:16.389 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 6
01-15 19:19:16.390 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 6
01-15 19:19:16.391 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 7
01-15 19:19:16.391 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 7
01-15 19:19:16.394 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 8
01-15 19:19:16.394 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 8
01-15 19:19:16.396 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 26
01-15 19:19:16.397 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 26
01-15 19:19:16.398 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 27
01-15 19:19:16.399 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 27
01-15 19:19:16.401 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 28
01-15 19:19:16.401 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 28
01-15 19:19:16.403 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 29
01-15 19:19:16.404 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 29
01-15 19:19:16.405 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 30
01-15 19:19:16.405 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 30
01-15 19:19:16.407 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 31
01-15 19:19:16.407 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 31
01-15 19:19:16.656 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 6
01-15 19:19:16.658 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 6
01-15 19:19:16.658 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 7
01-15 19:19:16.659 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 7
01-15 19:19:16.660 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 8
01-15 19:19:16.660 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 8
01-15 19:19:16.662 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 26
01-15 19:19:16.662 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 26
01-15 19:19:16.663 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 27
01-15 19:19:16.664 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 27
01-15 19:19:16.665 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 28
01-15 19:19:16.665 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 28
01-15 19:19:16.674 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 29
01-15 19:19:16.675 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 29
01-15 19:19:16.676 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 30
01-15 19:19:16.676 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 30
01-15 19:19:16.678 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 31
01-15 19:19:16.678 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 31
01-15 19:19:16.679 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 4
01-15 19:19:16.679 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 4
01-15 19:19:16.680 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 4, VIEW ID: 0
01-15 19:19:16.681 7596-7596/? I/OUTPUT: getDropDownView: DB ID: 6, VIEW ID: 0
```

Comment: and what's the question?

Comment: Could you post the output values for each crsCheckCatAva.getInt(crsCheckCatAva.getColumnIndex("category_id")) and category.getCategory_id() calls over while loop?

Comment: @AntonKazakov I want to change the background color of the items in spinner but those items will be filtered through a query.

Comment: @AlexTa I've updated the question please have a look

Answer (score 0):

The problem here, is that your query returns more than one result(it seems that returns 2 results per query, **DB ID: 4**  and **DB ID: 6**), and you are iterating over the cursor inside `getDropDownView` method.

So, this produces that your dropdown view's background color is going to be **always** the value which meets your `if-else` statement condition the second time.

Comment: If I don't run my query inside my getDropDownView method how will it get the updated data for me?